# Picture a cross section of a microchannel model

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have been working on a simulation of a micromixer. The results of my simulation are datapoints representing a coordinate in space and the value of a concentration belonging to that coordinate. Using Matlab I am trying to create two dimensional plots of these cross sections in which the color of the plots refers to a certain concentration.

I did some research about how other people plot scattered data plots. I got the following snippet of code which almost does exactly what I want:

```
x_max=max(data(:,1)); %get max and min coordinates of datapoints

x_min=min(data(:,1));

y_max=max(data(:,2));

y_min=min(data(:,2));

figure(1);

%snap the datapoints to a grid

[xi,yi] = meshgrid(x_min:(x_max-x_min)/1000:x_max, y_min:(y_max-y_min)/1000:y_max); 

zi = griddata(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3),xi,yi,'linear');

%plot the data using surf

surf(xi,yi,zi,'EdgeColor','None');

%get the correct viewpoint

view(2);
```

The only problem with this code is that it does not obey the borders of my channel. It creates extra data outside the original borders. You can see this in the two images I attached. One image contains the actual datapoints and hence you can see what the cross section of the channel looks like. The other one is the plot generated with the method I just described.

Does somebody know a workaround for this? Such that I can make the colorplot and keep the original shape of the cross section.

The datapoints which make clear what the actual cross section of the channel looks like
[image]

The image generated with surf
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`griddata` is an interpolating function so it's simply interpolated for all regions of the grid that are enclosed by the straight lines between any two of the points - i.e. the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). As far as the function is concerned, there's no formal distinction between the unwanted regions in the surface and the small spaces between the points in the interior of the cross section, except that the points it's interpolating between happen to be an arbitrary amount further apart.

Since the computational penalty for calculating the interpolation for those unwanted regions is small, the quickest fix is to delete the part of the surface that you don't want after it's been created. The most reliable way to do this will be if you have a definition for that boundary from another source. If you don't, for the example data you showed [`boundary`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html) should do a good job of figuring it out:

```
k = boundary(data(:,1),data(:,2));
```

You can then delete interpolated values outside of this value before you plot the surface by setting their value in the grid to `NaN`:

```
zi(~inpolygon(xi,yi,data(k,1),data(k,2))) = NaN;
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and in some cases it improves the image, but in others it does not. I think this mainly has to do with the density of datapoints. I tried playing with the shrink factor 's' for the boundary function but where in one dataset the result is improved, the result is worse in another. I might make a definition for the boundary, but the cross section is not the same in each region of the channel and also the orientation is different.

Comment: Can you post an example of a set of points where `boundary` performs poorly? If the boundary is always made up of primitive features (union of a circle and a rectangle?) you could perhaps achieve more reliable result by constructing those primitives to fit around the points.